# Clicking twice on a radiobutton generates illegalstateexception

Tags: android, radio-button, illegalstateexception

I am getting an object of `RadioButton` by using `findViewById()` and then setting an `onclicklistener' for it.The code goes like :

```
final EditText editTextView = (EditText)findViewById(2001);
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {


                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editTextGroupLayout);
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                editTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
                editTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL| InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
                editTextView.setId(2001);
                linearLayout.addView(editTextView);




             }
         });
```

When i click **Once** on the `radiobutton` it works fine.But when i click it **twice**,it generates

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

By clicking it twice why this exception occurs?

**What i tried**

I tried to remove the line `final EditText editTextView = (EditText)findViewById(2001);`
and add this line inside the `onClick()`,`EditText editTextView = (EditText)findViewById(2001);`.But by doing this it doesn't get executed even once.It shows `exception` too.

Comment: do You want to add editext on every click of RadiButton??

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to do exactly? Perhaps you wanted to show/hide the `EditText` instead of add/remove it? As for the error, it was caused by adding an already existing `EditText`.

Comment: Yes wanted to add edittext or show/hide it after each click.Adam has answered it which worked for me.Please check the answer.Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is beacouse you got only one instance of edittext which alerady has a parent after first click. Try to remove view from parent and than place it again.
Or maybe try to show/hide it?

You should propably do something like this.

```
linearLayout.removeAllViews(); or linearLayout.removeView(editTextView);
...
linearLayout.addView(editTextView);
```

Comment: Hey @Adam.That was the issue there.Your solution worked.Thanks for explaining.